# Getting time out exception when run this query from vs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

[image: Category]

[image: Questions]

this are the my table structure i need each category subcategory's count and question count of the related category where Isparent=1 from category table  this is my result table

[image]
This is my code 
My prob is it run in sql server while running from application(VS) it throw a time our error 
where i did mistake help me out frnds.
thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (CategoryID INT,NAME VARCHAR(52))
INSERT INTO @TEMP SELECT CategoryID,Name FROM EC_M_CategoriesMaster    where IsParent=1  

DECLARE @TEMP1 TABLE ( CategoryID INT,cCOUNTS INT)
INSERT INTO @TEMP1 SELECT te.CategoryID,COUNT((ISNULL(te1.PCategoryID,0)))
AS Ccount from @TEMP te inner join  EC_M_CategoriesMaster te1 on te.CategoryID=te1.PCategoryID  GROUP BY te.CategoryID

DECLARE @TEMP2 TABLE (CategoryID INT,COUNTS INT )
INSERT INTO @TEMP2 SELECT CategoryID,COUNT((ISNULL(QuestionID,0)))
AS Qcount from EC_M_QuestionMaster GROUP BY CategoryID  
SELECT t1.CategoryID,t1.Name,ISNULL(t.COUNTS,0) as Qcount,ISNULL(MY.cCOUNTS,0) AS CatCount from
@TEMP2 t RIGHT OUTER JOIN   
@TEMP t1 ON t.CategoryID=t1.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN @TEMP1 MY ON  MY.CategoryID=T1.CategoryID
```

Comment: How many records in each table? Do you have any indexes?

Comment: records has no limit.i don't have any indexes